# how to get the user input from prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, impromptu

I have this code (in jQuery Impormptu):

```
var statesdemo = {
    state0: {
        title: 'Name',
        html:'<label>name <input type="text" name="name" value=""></label><br />',
        buttons: { Next: 1 },
        submit:function(e,v,m,f){ 
            console.log(f);

            e.preventDefault();
            $.prompt.goToState('state1');
        }
    },  
    state1: {
        title: 'choice',
        html:'<label>choice: <select name="travel" multiple>'+
        '<option value="1" selected>1</option>'+
        '<option value="2">2</option>'+
        '</select></label>',
        buttons: { Back: -1, Done: 1 },
        focus: 1,
        submit:function(e,v,m,f){ 
            console.log(f);

            e.preventDefault();
            if(v==1) {$.prompt.close();}
            if(v==-1) $.prompt.goToState('state0');
        }
    }
};
```

and with simple jquery I have this snippet:

```
$('#id').bind("dblclick", function() {
  console.log('target id: ' + event.target.id);
  f = $.prompt(statesdemo);
});
```

how can I get the user input when the prompt is finished?
the $.prompt does not return anything.
Also, the problem is that the $.prompt is a non blocking function. so the programs continues without waiting the user input.

Comment: If this plugin's sole purpose is to emulate native window.prompt in DHTML, and it doesn't even tell you how to capture user input, it might be worth ditching the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            $('#my_a').click(function() {
                f = $.prompt(statesdemo);
                if(f.name!==undefined){
                      console.log(f.name);
                }
                if(f.travel!==undefined){
                      console.log(f.travel);
                }
            });
```

Comment: thx for your answer. The problem is that the `$.prompt` is a non blocking function. so the programs continues without waiting the user input. (I check that in inspect element with break point).

Answer (score 0):

[I've created a demo with an extra button that logs user input](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/md2CY/).

You can achieve this by creating an object to contain user input within Impromptu objects.

```
var userInput = {};
```

Next, create a function that takes a form input change event, and assigns the input's current value to a property in the object we just created with the same name as the input.

```
function registerUserInput( changeEvent ){
    var input = changeEvent.target;

    userInput[ input.name ] = $( input ).val();
};
```

Then we create an event listener on the body for all `change` events that occur within an Impromptu wrapper (`.jquibox`)

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'change', '.jqibox *', registerUserInput );
```

From this point onwards if ever an input within an Impromptu changes, its value will be recorded in the `userInput` object. So, to get the `name` input in your example:

```
userInput.name
```